# Textfiles did not come along with class files - executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files, executable-jar

Today I encountered problems to launch a jar-file for the first time. Now I know (after unzipping the jar) that the textfiles did not come along when I did the export and creation of a jar-package of my program in Eclipse.

Why does the textfiles not come along with the class files? Where should I put those in the project?

*I put the textfiles in the root of the project folder*

Greaful for help

EDIT: probably I can do it manually in the cmd but I dont know what I should add in the programcode where the textfiles are loaded. Should I for instance impelent a classloader?
I know how to do so when loading images such as jpg org gif. But what if it is a textfile?

Here is the method responsible for loading textfiles

```
    private void read(String text_file, int len, int index) {

    String[] stringBuffer = new String[len]; 
    File file = new File(text_file);
    FileReader fileReader;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer[i] = line; 
            i++;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnde) {
        fnde.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "files could not be found", "Help", 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    splitString(stringBuffer, index);   
}
```

Comment: put them in the the source folder. for example in META-INF and change your load method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example from your code. The file text.txt is in the source folder under META-INF.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadFile o = new ReadFile();
        o.read("test.txt", 2, 0);
    }
    private void read(String text_file, int len, int index) {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
        String[] stringBuffer = new String[len]; 
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/".concat(text_file))));

            String line;
            int i = 0;
            while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer[i] = line; 
                i++;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnde) {
            fnde.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "files could not be found", "Help", 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        splitString(stringBuffer, index);   
    }

    private void splitString(String[] stringBuffer, int index) {
        for(String line: stringBuffer) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks i am looking into this right now. BUt I am not sure where I should create this META_INF-folder? I can see its automatically created when the jar-is created and where the manifest is placed. But how do I start? create this folder in a certain place in Eclipse, place the textfile there and then export the project as an executable jar-file?

Comment: create the META-INF folder in the source folder of the java project. the folder where your sources files go without package. normally  
'src'

Answer (score 0):

Only folders/jars listed under  -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export will be exported into the JAR. Place the files into a folder, which is on your build path by

- adding any folder as source folder (  -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source)
- or putting the file into a sub-folder of your standard *src* folder.

the base folder of your project is not and should/can not be part of the export.